# How do I create a Line Item without end date in Google Ad Manager (DFP)?

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I am using Google Ad Manager to display ads on my website. I am trying to combine it with Adtraction (adtraction.com) to display some affiliate ads. These should take priority over the default AdSense.

Since these affiliate ads should be continuous, I tried leaving the end date empty, but that is not possible. Also, I'm unsure what I should set the CPM to, since it doesn't allow 0.

> How do I create a Line Item without end date in Google Ad Manager (DFP)?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried leaving the end date empty, but that is not possible

Click on the end date field, then select "Unlimited":

[image]

As for your second question: Personally I am able to set the CPM to zero.

Comment: The "Unlimited" option does not appear to me. However, setting CPM to 0 worked.